# Generate result in CSV file using prepared statement query in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedures

I have created this query to generate report and its working fine but i want to download the result of this query in .CSV file. How to execute this query in laravel ?
Query :

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when  wm.SubPointId = ''',
       wm.SubPointId,
      ''' then Balance else 0 end) AS ',
      REPLACE ( ws.SubPointType, ' ', '' )
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM wallet_master wm, wallet_subpoints ws WHERE wm.SubPointId = ws.SubPointId;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT MobileNo, ', @sql, ', sum(Balance) as `TotalBalance`
                  FROM wallet_master wm  
                  GROUP BY MobileNo');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I would place this code into a stored procedure, and that call that proc from Laravel.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was about to edit the closure list to fix my mistake. Please next time do not abuse the reopen vote, edit the closure list instead. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Please read the entire question before voting or closing, thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen will do, thanks

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how do i place this code in stored procedure?